# Span is flickering on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I have created a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xfc7H/. here when I hover the mouse on the text `resize` it flickers. So that means the event is being propagated. I want this text to appear stable when I hover on it. Please if someone can resolve the issue.

the html

```
         <div class="jqte_editor" >
         <img width=100px height=100px stye=" border:1px solid #eee;" src='http://appendto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/training-hero.jpg'></img>
         </div>
```

the jquery

```
     $('.jqte_editor').on('mousedown', 'span', function() {

        $("#imagecontainer").has(this).prepend("<div style='font-size:10px; position:absolute; background-color:#eee; opacity:1; width:70px; top:" + $(this).position().top + "; left:" + $(this).position().left + ";' id='imageresizer'>Width:<input type='text' style='width:25px; opacity:1.0;' id='imagewidth'></input><br> height:<input type='text' id='imageheight' style='width:25px'></input></div>");
        return false;
    });
    $('.jqte_editor').on('mouseenter', 'span', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.jqte_editor').on('mouseenter', 'img', function() {
        $(this).wrap("<div id='imagecontainer' style='float:left; position:relative;'></div>");
        $("#imagecontainer").prepend("<span style='position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; background-color:#eee; color:#888;' id='spanresize'>resize</span>");
    });
    $('.jqte_editor').on('mouseleave', 'img', function() {
        $("#spanresize").remove();
        $("#imagecontainer> img").unwrap();

    });
    $('.jqte_editor').on('mousedown', 'img', function() { $("#spanresizer").remove(); $("#imageresizer").remove(); $("#imagecontainer> img").unwrap(); });
    $('.jqte_editor').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
        var imagelement = $("#imagecontainer").find('img');
        console.log(imagelement);
        var width = $("#imagewidth").val();
        var height = $("#imageheight").val();
        console.log(width);
        imagelement.attr("width", width);
        imagelement.attr("height", height);
    });
```

Comment: A link to jsFiddle isn't enough, you must include code that reproduces your problem in your question.

Comment: I've made my own sample, showing how to properly stop propagation: http://jsfiddle.net/5szHw/

Comment: I have inclued the code with the question. and I know how about that. I have done similar up there. but that is not working

Comment: It works with delegated events too: http://jsfiddle.net/5szHw/1/ reduce your test case down to a smaller sample. It obviously works, so you'll need to reduce yours down until you figure out what about it is causing the issue.

Comment: Do me a favor: `var jqteEditor = $('.jqte_editor');`

Comment: incase the image is not visible I update the image. http://jsfiddle.net/xfc7H/1/

Comment: The issue is the mouseleave on the image. When you hover over the span, you're leaving the image, thus hiding the span, which results in hovering over the image again, which shows the span, thus causing an infinite loop represented by the flickering you are seeing. Simply commenting out that one event causes the flicker to stop (of course, it also makes it no longer work once you leave the span.) http://jsfiddle.net/xfc7H/3/

Comment: This is very bad. How to remedy this then?

Comment: Either make the span a child of the img (which is impossible,) or use a throttle that makes the image leave event not remove the elements if the element that is entered shortly thereafter is the span. This can be done with a setTimeout stored in a global variable with a 10ms delay that gets cleared on the mouseenter of the span.

Comment: @KevinB but I suppose the mouse has not left the image when I hover over the `spanresize`.

Comment: Oh, but it has, since the span isn't a child of the image. It may still be over it visually, but technically, it's over the span, and since the span is not inside the image, then the cursor also isn't in the image.

Comment: @KevinB whola!!!!!!!! I have been fasting all day. :)

Comment: I can swear I thought about this when I was starting to code. @KevinB

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/xfc7H/4/ now the flicker is gone, but now you have the opposite issue. Now, when you you leave the span, you're entering the image again which causing the resizespan to go away.

Comment: And, here it is fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/xfc7H/5/ just had to unwrap and remove the resize span on image enter.

Comment: Thanks!!! now this should be made into an answer... @KevinB

Comment: @KevinB This is one sweet trick. I loved this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when you hover over the span, you're leaving the image which results in the span being removed. When the span is removed, you're entering the image again, causing the span to be added, which again causes the image to be left, hiding the span yet again in an infinite loop which causes the flickering.

To solve this, you'll first need to create a throttle that will only remove the span if the image is left and the span isn't entered within 10 ms. To do this, create a global variable, then on image leave, store a setTimeout inside of it that removes the span. Now, on span enter, clear the timeout.

```
var resizeEnterTimer;
...
    .on('mouseleave', 'img', function() {
        resizeEnterTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#spanresize").remove();
            $("#imagecontainer> img").unwrap();
        },10);
    })
    .on('mouseenter', 'span', function () {
        clearTimeout(resizeEnterTimer);
    })
```

That fixes the flickering, however now you have the issue of multiple spans being added due to the image enter event being triggered when you leave the span.

To fix that, simply remove the span and unwrap the image on mouseenter of image.

```
.on('mouseenter', 'img', function () {
    $("#spanresize").remove();
    $("#imagecontainer> img").unwrap();
    $(this).wrap("<div id='imagecontainer' style='float:left; position:relative;'></div>");
    $("#imagecontainer").prepend("<span style='position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; background-color:#eee; color:#888;' id='spanresize'>resize</span>");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xfc7H/5/

Comment: I must say again .. One sweet solution.. I would have spent another hour  over on this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) to prevent bounces.

```
 $('.jqte_editor').on('mousedown', 'img', function(e) {
// your code

e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: actually the `span` appears above the image to display the option to `resize`. so I have to do that on the span not on the imag. like if I haver over resize text to select it and see the resize window.  `$('.jqte_editor').on('mouseenter', 'span', function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }); `

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls If you're interested I can give a try.